# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard resulting queries

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms

I am trying to import data from Oracle Database to SQL Server.
My approach is to import it with wizard .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle.
Does Import and Export Wizard create and run some query in this case?
I would like to get access to that query.

Comment: If you're importing an entire table it won't be doing anything but `SELECT * FROM Table`, if that (it might actually use direct table access APIs directly, depending on the driver). For inserting, it will use the bulk insert APIs. The actual data flow goes source -> local machine running SSMS -> destination. There is no "query" for you to use, at least not anything more interesting than what you would write yourself if you were using an explicit query as the source rather than specifying tables and views, but you can have the entire operation saved as an SSIS package.

Comment: So basically the same approach would be to connect to oracle and ssms servers with python, load data into some pd.dataframe and load it into ssms table. Am i right? And I would be able to tune the process with little batches as well.

Comment: SSMS is just a GUI front-end for SQL Server; it's not a database engine itself, so there's no such thing as an "SSMS server" or "table". And yes, doing it with Python would be *roughly* comparable, except that piping data through a dataframe from a scripting language will likely involve far more overhead than the direct operation from the import/export wizard. Doubly so if you're not using bulk insert from the client side, but regular insert statements (I don't know if Python has packages for leveraging bulk insert towards SQL Server). Those "little batches" would be far slower overall.

Comment: When all you have is a snake everything looks like it can be solved by Python

Comment: SSMS or any other software is written in some programming language, so *basically* workflow is the same for any programming language (including Python) and any database: generate source query -> extract the data to the medium -> generate "insert" statement -> pass the data to the target. Even if source and target are not databases at all. But it doesn't help you to solve the problem

Comment: "generate source query" - that's exactly the reason i created this thread for.